# ./a,out: error while loading shared libraries and linking

Tags: c++, loading, libraries

I'm trying to use portaudio and libaudiodecoder to write a simple c++ program to play a song, only I don't get that far...

test.cpp

```
#include "libs/portaudio/include/portaudio.h"   //portaudio
#include "libs/libaudiodecoder/include/audiodecoder.h" //libaudiodecoder

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    std::string filename = argv;

    AudioDecoderBase tester(filename);
    std::cout << "test complete" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I then run:

```
gcc -L/usr/local/lib -lstdc++ test.cpp -lportaudio -laudiodecoder
```

Which compiles (I get a warning to do with the type of argv saying it should be char**).

When I run a.out test.mp3 I get:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libaudiodecoder.so: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now, I had this error with portaudio too and I believe I fixed it by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib" then running sudo ldconfig. I checked /usr/local/lib and the libaudiodecoder.so file is there. So I'm confused, the environment variable is set (I double checked), the configuration is loaded, and the library file is in the correct directory.

note: I ran ls /usr/local/lib as I was writing this just to make sure the library was there, it shows up as a different colour in the terminal (green instead of cyan), however, I'm not sure what this says about the file.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: you are pointing to "local/lib" but your test.cpp file is pulling the libraries from a directory called "libs".  Is this possibly the issue?

Comment: What does `ldd a.out` show?

Comment: Often the different color signals that it is a different kind of file, but the exact meaning depends on your system. I connect cyan with soft links to an actual library, which is often the case with versioned libraries. Green may mean that it is an executable file. Would you like to show us the important part of the directory listing, i.e. execute:
`ls -la /usr/lib | grep libaudio`

Also: You really want to change `char* argv` to `char** argv` and get your filename from `argv[1]` instead from argv itself, as argv is the array of all parameters. Consider checking argc as well.

Comment: Expanding @mvw's comment: Please also show `ldd /usr/local/lib/libaudiodecoder.so`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your system is not configured to load libraries from /usr/local/lib. GCC used the path you gave to find the libraries, but the system dynamic loader uses its own path.

You will need to go to /etc/ld.so.conf or /etc/ld.so.conf.d and add /usr/local/lib as a path. Then run ldconfig to update the library cache.